# Assert or exit/die for checking headers_sent() in PHP?

Tags: php, security, assert

I am writing a PHP class for generation of HTML output. For security reasons, I need to ensure that no code has sent output before this class does. Here are the two options I thought of:

### Option 1: As an assertion

```
if( !$this->headersSent ) {
    assert( '!headers_sent()' );
    $this->headersSent = true;
    // ...
}
```

### Option 2: Using an `if` statement and `die()`

```
if( !$this->headersSent ) {
    if( headers_sent() ) {
        die( 'For security, refusing to continue: headers already sent.' );
    }
    $this->headersSent = true;
    // ...
}
```

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29#Comparison_with_error_handling), "Assertions should be used to document logically impossible situations and discover programming errors."

- This class is part of a specific application, and I consider it a programming error to send HTML output without using this class. So `assert()` should be used.
- On the other hand, this application might become open source one day, and someone might customize it. He might have assertions switched off, and so the resulting security problem might go unnoticed. So `die()` should be used.

Which one is better practice?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's important that the headers haven't already been sent. Can't you use output buffering and before outputing the HTML content, check the security implications and if there's a problem, don't print the supplied HTML and instead print your warning message.

Comment: dying is not an option. AT LEAST send appropriate header first, 503 or 403 first. However, I see nothing security related in sent headers. Care to explain your opinion?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It would bypass X-Frame-Options as well as a charset specified in the HTTP header. http://code.google.com/p/doctype/wiki/ArticleUtf7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably want to throw an Exception there.

```
class HeadersAlreadySentException extends Exception { }
throw new HeadersAlreadySentException('Headers already sent. Cannot continue.');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php